# Highcharts center on x and y axis offset

Tags: javascript, highcharts

First, for reference I'm trying to mimic this chart:

[image]

Currently my chart looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eA4Df/

What's the option to center the (1, 1) coordinates of the chart but still display all of the bubble data?

Current highcharts options are:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
    },
    xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#000000',
            width: 2,
            value: 1
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#000000',
            width: 2,
            value: 1
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set min and max values for the axis:

```
xAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        color: '#000000',
        width: 2,
        value: 1
    }],
    max: 2,
    min: 0
},
yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        color: '#000000',
        width: 2,
        value: 1
    }],
     max: 2,
    min: 0
},
```

Example [SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BCf82/1/)

Comment: Whoa, perfect! Thank you. Will marked as answered once the time limit is reached.

Comment: Actually, this might not work. Because if I have a coordinate outside of (2, 2), the bubble will go off the chart. And if I set the max to 3 or 4, it still won't center on (1, 1)

Comment: Actually, this will do as I can do some post processing of the data and calculate the min and max. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of plotLines, you can move your axis by [offset parameter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset) or use [plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values)